# Why do we need to import "org.junit.Assert " static?

Tags: java, junit, assert

I tried to enter **assertTrue** into code and found that i need to import ***junit*** lib.

In this code,

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
//import org.junit.Assert;   with this didnt worked

public class Person implements Serializable {
       // some code there

        assertTrue(p2.getAge() == p.getAge());
        assertTrue(p2.getName().equals(p.getName()));
}
```

So i tried with `import org.junit.Assert;`
but that asserTrue didnt worked then I tried with `import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;` and then it works. I need explanation *why need static ?*

Comment: you don't "have to", you can also just call the static method without a static import

Comment: no need, imports are optional, just use `org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(p2.getAge() == p.getAge());`, that is, the fully qualified name of the class/method... clearly it looks *better*, more readable, using the import

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the `static` keyword you can use the methods without qualifying the class the method belongs to. See this relevant part in the documentation:

> The static import construct allows unqualified access to static members without inheriting from the type containing the static members. Instead, the program imports the members [...]

[Static import](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/static-import.html)